# Unable to find jsonpath in deeply nested array with duplicate keys

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I have a deeply nested json as below :

```html
[
    [
        {
            "heading": "Account Information",
            "columns": 2,
            "id": "01B5g000015Z7yeEAC",
            "rows": 8,
            "collapsible": false,
            "useHeading": false,
            "layoutRows": [
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": false,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Rating",
                                    "label": "Account Rating"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Rating",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Name",
                                    "label": "Account Name"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Account Name",
                            "lookupIdApiName": "Id",
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": true
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Phone",
                                    "label": "Account Phone"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Phone",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "ParentId",
                                    "label": "Parent Account ID"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Parent Account",
                            "lookupIdApiName": "ParentId",
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Fax",
                                    "label": "Account Fax"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Fax",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "AccountNumber",
                                    "label": "Account Number"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Account Number",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Website",
                                    "label": "Website"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Website",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Site",
                                    "label": "Account Site"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Account Site",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "TickerSymbol",
                                    "label": "Ticker Symbol"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Ticker Symbol",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Type",
                                    "label": "Account Type"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Type",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Ownership",
                                    "label": "Ownership"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Ownership",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Industry",
                                    "label": "Industry"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Industry",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "NumberOfEmployees",
                                    "label": "Employees"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Employees",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "AnnualRevenue",
                                    "label": "Annual Revenue"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Annual Revenue",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Sic",
                                    "label": "SIC Code"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "SIC Code",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "heading": "Address Information",
            "columns": 2,
            "id": "01B5g000015Z7yhEAC",
            "rows": 1,
            "collapsible": false,
            "useHeading": false,
            "layoutRows": [
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "BillingStreet",
                                    "label": "Billing Street"
                                },
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "BillingCity",
                                    "label": "Billing City"
                                },
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "BillingState",
                                    "label": "Billing State/Province"
                                },
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "BillingPostalCode",
                                    "label": "Billing Zip/Postal Code"
                                },
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "BillingCountry",
                                    "label": "Billing Country"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Billing Address",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "ShippingStreet",
                                    "label": "Shipping Street"
                                },
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "ShippingCity",
                                    "label": "Shipping City"
                                },
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "ShippingState",
                                    "label": "Shipping State/Province"
                                },
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "ShippingPostalCode",
                                    "label": "Shipping Zip/Postal Code"
                                },
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "ShippingCountry",
                                    "label": "Shipping Country"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Shipping Address",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "heading": "Additional Information",
            "columns": 2,
            "id": "01B5g000015Z7yfEAC",
            "rows": 4,
            "collapsible": false,
            "useHeading": false,
            "layoutRows": [
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "CustomerPriority__c",
                                    "label": "Customer Priority"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Customer Priority",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "SLA__c",
                                    "label": "SLA"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "SLA",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "SLAExpirationDate__c",
                                    "label": "SLA Expiration Date"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "SLA Expiration Date",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "SLASerialNumber__c",
                                    "label": "SLA Serial Number"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "SLA Serial Number",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "NumberofLocations__c",
                                    "label": "Number of Locations"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Number of Locations",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "UpsellOpportunity__c",
                                    "label": "Upsell Opportunity"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Upsell Opportunity",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Active__c",
                                    "label": "Active"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Active",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                        
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "heading": "System Information",
            "columns": 2,
            "id": "01B5g000015Z7ygEAC",
            "rows": 1,
            "collapsible": false,
            "useHeading": false,
            "layoutRows": [
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        
                        
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "heading": "Description Information",
            "columns": 1,
            "id": "01B5g000015Z7yiEAC",
            "rows": 1,
            "collapsible": false,
            "useHeading": false,
            "layoutRows": [
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Description",
                                    "label": "Account Description"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Description",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "heading": "Custom Links",
            "columns": 3,
            "id": "01B5g000015Z7ydEAC",
            "rows": 1,
            "collapsible": false,
            "useHeading": false,
            "layoutRows": [
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        
                        
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "heading": "Account Information",
            "columns": 2,
            "id": "01B5g000015Z7yeEAC",
            "rows": 8,
            "collapsible": false,
            "useHeading": false,
            "layoutRows": [
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Rating",
                                    "label": "Account Rating"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Rating",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Name",
                                    "label": "Account Name"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Account Name",
                            "lookupIdApiName": "Id",
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": true
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Phone",
                                    "label": "Account Phone"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Phone",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "ParentId",
                                    "label": "Parent Account ID"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Parent Account",
                            "lookupIdApiName": "ParentId",
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Fax",
                                    "label": "Account Fax"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Fax",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "AccountNumber",
                                    "label": "Account Number"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Account Number",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Website",
                                    "label": "Website"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Website",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Site",
                                    "label": "Account Site"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Account Site",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "TickerSymbol",
                                    "label": "Ticker Symbol"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Ticker Symbol",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Type",
                                    "label": "Account Type"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Type",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Ownership",
                                    "label": "Ownership"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Ownership",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Industry",
                                    "label": "Industry"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Industry",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "NumberOfEmployees",
                                    "label": "Employees"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Employees",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "AnnualRevenue",
                                    "label": "Annual Revenue"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Annual Revenue",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Sic",
                                    "label": "SIC Code"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "SIC Code",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "heading": "Address Information",
            "columns": 2,
            "id": "01B5g000015Z7yhEAC",
            "rows": 1,
            "collapsible": false,
            "useHeading": false,
            "layoutRows": [
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "BillingStreet",
                                    "label": "Billing Street"
                                },
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "BillingCity",
                                    "label": "Billing City"
                                },
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "BillingState",
                                    "label": "Billing State/Province"
                                },
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "BillingPostalCode",
                                    "label": "Billing Zip/Postal Code"
                                },
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "BillingCountry",
                                    "label": "Billing Country"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Billing Address",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "ShippingStreet",
                                    "label": "Shipping Street"
                                },
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "ShippingCity",
                                    "label": "Shipping City"
                                },
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "ShippingState",
                                    "label": "Shipping State/Province"
                                },
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "ShippingPostalCode",
                                    "label": "Shipping Zip/Postal Code"
                                },
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "ShippingCountry",
                                    "label": "Shipping Country"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Shipping Address",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "heading": "Additional Information",
            "columns": 2,
            "id": "01B5g000015Z7yfEAC",
            "rows": 4,
            "collapsible": false,
            "useHeading": false,
            "layoutRows": [
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "CustomerPriority__c",
                                    "label": "Customer Priority"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Customer Priority",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "SLA__c",
                                    "label": "SLA"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "SLA",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "SLAExpirationDate__c",
                                    "label": "SLA Expiration Date"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "SLA Expiration Date",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "SLASerialNumber__c",
                                    "label": "SLA Serial Number"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "SLA Serial Number",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "NumberofLocations__c",
                                    "label": "Number of Locations"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Number of Locations",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        },
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "UpsellOpportunity__c",
                                    "label": "Upsell Opportunity"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Upsell Opportunity",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Active__c",
                                    "label": "Active"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Active",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                        
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "heading": "System Information",
            "columns": 2,
            "id": "01B5g000015Z7ygEAC",
            "rows": 1,
            "collapsible": false,
            "useHeading": false,
            "layoutRows": [
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                    
                        
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "heading": "Description Information",
            "columns": 1,
            "id": "01B5g000015Z7yiEAC",
            "rows": 1,
            "collapsible": false,
            "useHeading": false,
            "layoutRows": [
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        {
                            "editableForUpdate": true,
                            "editableForNew": true,
                            "layoutComponents": [
                                {
                                    "componentType": "Field",
                                    "apiName": "Description",
                                    "label": "Account Description"
                                }
                            ],
                            "label": "Description",
                            "lookupIdApiName": null,
                            "sortable": false,
                            "required": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "heading": "Custom Links",
            "columns": 3,
            "id": "01B5g000015Z7ydEAC",
            "rows": 1,
            "collapsible": false,
            "useHeading": false,
            "layoutRows": [
                {
                    "layoutItems": [
                        
                        
                        
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

And I need the value of all labels which have **editableForUpdate** as **true**  here :
[image]

Ive tried JSONpath as **$..layoutRows.[?(@.editableForUpdate == true)])].label** but it does not provide the desired value of labels and gives duplicative values.

Can you please help me write the correct JSONPATH expression ?

Comment: After a few head scratching attempts, Ive been able to get the labels with **$..layoutRows.[?(@.editableForUpdate == true)].[*].label**  , but now the same jsonpath is returning zero search results in the JAVA code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below **JSONPath**

```
$..layoutItems[?(@.editableForUpdate == true)].layoutComponents[*].label
```

Online Tool For [Jayway JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#jayway-jsonpath) (A Java  DSL)   : https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I did a similar one with "$..[?(@.editableForUpdate == true)].layoutComponents..label" . Thanks for the help..